# CSS icon does not properly align

Tags: html, css

The SoundCloud icon on my website is not properly aligned with the icon in the center. This can be seen after scrolling down at https://intersexmusic.com
How do I fix this? Code is below.

```
.fa {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by adding the following rules which will affect all icons in this area of the DOM. By absolutely positioning the icons within relative containers and accounting for their own width using negative `translate(-50%, -50%)` values, we can perfectly center the icons.

If you didn't include this line…

```css
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

…the icons would appear too far left and too far from the top. The reason is that when you position something `top: 50%`, the actual size of the item you're positioning is not considered in the calculation. That's why we need the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` line, to account for the actual dimensions of the item we're positioning.

```
.card-body .fa {
  position: relative;
}

.card-body .fa::before {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the approach. Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: @pravinpoudel I added another paragraph in my answer which will hopefully help you better understand the solution.

Comment: I didn't know that translate with percentage take percentage of own dimension. What I understood is that the top and left percentages didn't work because the center is transformed in both the x-axis and y-axis so to compensate it we translate it with half of its dimension.

Comment: or, in clear words, icon's top end is positioned 50% away from the top in both axis so to put the midpoint of an icon in the center, it is translated b own half-length and width. Please Correct me. You have great sense man !!! Thanks for the knowledge you shared.

Comment: @pravinpoudel `top: 50%; left50%` is referring to 50% of the height/width of the element's *container*. To consider the element *itself*, we need to `translate(-50%, -50%)`. Those values refer to the height and width of the element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems SoundCloud icons need more space than what is left after the padding you applied on `.fa` class.

Try changing it from `padding: 20px` to `padding: 17px 13px`.

[image]

It aligns as above after changing padding.